# change highlight color of

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

please see this link
[a link](http://ri.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEV0w1UyRTQ3EAakdXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByMG04Z2o2BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2JmMQR2dGlkAw--/RV=1/RE=1394975926/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2ftympanus.net%2fcodrops%2f2013%2f05%2f08%2fresponsive-retina-ready-menu%2f/RS=%5EADAAeYN7u1oFlFS9NWV3b_NcK_.Vr8-)

by hover on link we can see a circle highlight around the icon, can we change color of highlight? for example red or blue?

I looked at `highlightNav.js` also all css but dont find where we can change the color of highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would notice line 235 of `component.css`

```
.nav i {
 ....
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);

 ....
```

It uses a white background with 10% opacity, that means that is adapting to its background color, you might want to change the color in there. You should be more keen on inspecting the css first before jumping to javascript, because this type of things are done using css mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
we can change it using below code

```
/* Animate the box-shadow to create the effect */
.no-touch #horizontalMenu .nav a:hover i,
.no-touch #horizontalMenu .nav a:active i,
.no-touch #horizontalMenu .nav a:focus i {      
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
```